# The route cant get the id from the form (Missing required parameters for [Route: update_user])

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

When i go to the page:`blog.local/user/1` it returns this error:

> Missing required parameters for [Route: update_user] [URI:
>   user/{user}/update]. (View:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\resources\views\login_pages\user.blade.php)

This is the view `user.blade.php`:

```php
<h2 class="mypositionclass" > welcome user: {{$user->surname . " " . $user->name}}</h2>
<hr>

<div style="text-align: center" >
    {{Form::open(['route'=>'update_user' , 'id' => $user->id]) }}
    <div>
        {{Form::label('name','Name: ',['style'=>'h3'])}}<br>
        {{Form::text('name','',['class'=>'input', 'placeholder'=>'insert name..'])}}
    </div>
    <div>
        {{Form::label('surname','Surname: ',['style'=>'h3'])}}<br>
        {{Form::text('surname','',['class'=>'input', 'placeholder'=>'insert surname..'])}}
    </div>
    <div>
        {{Form::label('email','Email: ',['style'=>'h3'])}}<br>
        {{Form::email('email','',['class'=>'input', 'placeholder'=>'insert email..'])}}
    </div>
    <div>
        {{Form::label('password','Password: ',['style'=>'h3'])}}<br>
        {{Form::password('passeword',['class'=>'input', 'placeholder'=>'insert password..'])}}
    </div>
    <div>
        {{Form::submit('update',['class'=>'button', 'style' => 'background-color: blue'])}}<br><br>
        {{Form::close()}}
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the route:

```php
Route::post('/user/{user}/update', 'Login_pageController@update')->name('update_user');
```

This is the function `update()` from `Login_pageController.php`:

```php
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $request::validate([
        'name'=>'required',
        'surname'=>'required',
        'email'=>'required',
        'password'=>'required'
    ]);

    $user=User::findOrFail($id);
    $user->name= $request->name;
    $user->surname= $request->surname;
    $user->email= $request->email;
    $user->password= $request->password;
    $user->save();
    return view('login_pages.login_page');
}
```

Comment: i think you can use just `{{ Form::open(['route'=>'update_user', $user->id]) }}` (remove the `'id' =>`), or pass it as an array `{{ Form::open([ 'route'=>'update_user' , ['id' => $user->id] ]) }}`

Comment: cool!. Someone had written an answer and then deleted it, I don't know why. Note that LaravelCollective also has [Form Model Binding](https://github.com/LaravelCollective/docs/blob/5.8/html.md#form-model-binding) for when you want to make updates

Comment: @sergioo The best way to say `thank you` here on SO is to `accept` and `upvote` @porloscerros-Ψ answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use just remove the `'id' =>`:

```
{{ Form::open(['route'=>'update_user', $user->id]) }}
```

or pass it as an array:

```
{{ Form::open([ 'route'=>'update_user' , ['id' => $user->id] ]) }}
```

Note that LaravelCollective also has [Form Model Binding](https://github.com/LaravelCollective/docs/blob/5.8/html.md#form-model-binding) for when you want to make updates.

> Often, you will want to populate a form based on the contents of a model. To do so, use the `Form::model` method:
>
> `{{ Form::model($user, ['route' => ['update_user', $user->id]]) }}`
>
> Now, when you generate a form element, like a text input, the model's value
>   matching the field's name will automatically be set as the field
>   value.