# Laravel 8 get current route parameters

Tags: php, laravel, locale, laravel-routing, laravel-8

i have dropdown to change locale in navigation menu. But i dont know that how can i get parameters.
How can i get current parameter?

Current parameters: slug,quiz_id,id and etc

**navigaiton menu blade:**

```html
<a class="dropdown-item" href="{{route(Route::currentRouteName(),'az')}}"> Az </a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="{{route(Route::currentRouteName(),'en')}}"> En </a>
```

I have different route.

**Web.php**

```php
Route::group(['prefix'=>'{language}'],function(){
    Route::get('quiz/{slug}',[MainController::class,'quiz_join'])->name('quiz_join');
    Route::get('quiz/{quiz_id}/questions/{id}', [QuestionController::class, 'destroy'] )->whereNumber('id')->name('question.destroy');
});
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The route cant get the id from the form (Missing required parameters for \[Route: update\_user\])](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57739611/the-route-cant-get-the-id-from-the-form-missing-required-parameters-for-route)

Comment: No my href="{{route(Route::currentRouteName(),'az')}}" located in navbar. That is different situation

Comment: @EsTeAa well for once I think this is actually a decent question so not sure about the question downvotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't find another way and something else doesn't exist you can use `URL::toRoute()` and use the current route and pull the parameters from it:

```
URL::toRoute($cur = Route::current(), ['language' => 'az'] + $cur->parameters(), true)
```

You could make a macro for this to simplify it a bit:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;

URL::macro('toCurrentRouteWithParameters', function (array $parameters = [], $absolute = true) {
    $current = Route::current();
    return $this->toRoute($current, $parameters + $current->parameters(), $absolute);
});
```

You can add this to a Service Provider's `boot` method.

Then you can call it in your Blade template:

```
{{ URL::toCurrentRouteWithParameters(['language' => 'az']) }}
```

If you don't want to use the macro then just try the first part:

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ URL::toRoute($cur = Route::current(), ['language' => 'az'] + $cur->parameters(), true) }}"> Az </a>
```

Comment: Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException
Route [http://127.0.0.1:8000/az/dashboard] not defined. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\quiz\resources\views\navigation-menu.blade.php)
http://127.0.0.1:8000/az/dashboard

Comment: @SahmarQuluzade add the route definition for this 'dashboard' route to your question since it isn't one of the routes you have listed

Comment: Call to a member function parameters() on string (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\quiz\resources\views\navigation-menu.blade.php)

Comment: that can't be the case ... `Route::current()` returns the current Route instance or `null` ... it can't be a string ... https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php#L1100

Comment: seems like you are calling `URL::current()` not `Route::current()`

Comment: @SahmarQuluzade copy and paste the last line in this updated version, you don't have to alter it to see if it works

Answer (score -2):

The default language for your application is stored in the `config/app.php` configuration file's `locale` configuration option. You are free to modify this value to suit the needs of your application.

**You may modify the default language for a single HTTP request at runtime using the `setLocale` method provided by the `App` facade:**

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;

Route::get('/greeting/{locale}', function ($locale) {
    if (! in_array($locale, ['en', 'es', 'fr'])) {
        abort(400);
    }

    App::setLocale($locale);

    //
});
```

You may configure a "fallback language", which will be used when the active language does not contain a given translation string. Like the default language, the fallback language is also configured in the `config/app.php` configuration file:

```
'fallback_locale' => 'en',
```

#### Determining The Current Locale

You may use the `currentLocale` and `isLocale` methods on the `App` facade to determine the current locale or check if the locale is a given value:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;

$locale = App::currentLocale();

if (App::isLocale('en')) {
    //
}
```

My recommendation is that you create a middleware to change the user language accordingly.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use App;
use Closure;

class Localization
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param \Closure $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (session()->has('locale')) {
            App::setlocale(session()->get('locale'));
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Finally, add the middleware you created to kernel.php under the middlewareGroups array.

```
/**
 * The application's route middleware groups.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Laravel\Jetstream\Http\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\HandleInertiaRequests::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\Localization::class, // <- Localization Middleware
    ],

    'api' => [
        'throttle:api',
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],
];
```

Comment: this has nothing to do with what they are trying to do

Comment: This has everything to do with understanding what he is trying to do. This is the best way to change the language by a parameter in the route.

Comment: If he does something similar to what I did here it will work to solve his problem. It doesn't matter if it doesn't answer his question exactly, as I still try to recommend best practice and not just anything to answer his question.

Comment: this has nothing to do with setting a locale, the question has nothing to do with that .. it is about getting the route parameters for the current route and generating a URL to the current route including those parameters ... what you have here has nothing to do with that again ... here is the title "Laravel 8 get current route parameters"  has nothing to do with setting a locale

Comment: The error says the `{slug}` parameter is missing though, nothing about language

Comment: sorry. that is not my question's answer.

Comment: If you do what I try to explain here you will have no more problems about missing parameters. Since laravel will automatically do it for you. But well, I think I explained it in a way that someone who is new could not understand at the first time. My bad